# How to fix or handle a glitched NPC?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-online

There are several NPCs who are known for glitching. For example, yesterday I walked to a NPC for continuing a quest and started a conversation. After the first option to select, I was able to read the answer for one second, then the conversation closed and since then I can't start it anymore.

When I move away from him and approach again, he does his voice-acting like "hey I know you, talk to me", but it is not possible to start a conversation. Some other PCs standing around stated in the chat that this poor boy is known for glitching.

**How can I fix those glitched NPCs or are there ways to avoid glitching in first place?**

Some mates say it's possible to completely close the game and then login again to start in another instance on the server. Others say it can take up to 30 minutes that an instance gets resetted.

Is there no other option to just wait or do other things?

Comment: I think since it's an Online Game there is no one but zenimax who can really "fix" those NPCs. You can't really modify the game files  to fix something like that without violating the TOS. (Not sure tho  if there is a way)

Comment: That's for sure. But as you play in an instance of the world around you, there may be tricks to get into another instance, where one NPC hasn't glitched yet.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This happens with some quests (and even some world bosses) because of some bugs in ESO's instancing system. Unlike other mmorpgs where you chose one of many servers to create your character on, ESO runs on two "megaservers" (a North American and a European megaserver). This means there are hundreds of thousands -- potentially millions -- of players on your megasever. The game segregates clusters of players into separate instances on the megaserver for obvious reasons (overcrowding, performance, etc).

Furthermore, some quests have phased environments. When you exit a cave or house and the outside world suddenly looks and behaves differently than when you went inside, it's because you've been placed in the next phase of that quest's environment. If your friend hasn't advanced that far, you may not even see him/her in your phase.

So with all this server instancing and quest phase instancing going on, some quests are getting stuck when you try to interact with an NPC or object. At some point, your instance lost track of where you actually are supposed to be in the questline.

In most cases, the easiest way to resolve this is to load into a new instance on your megaserver. Loading into a new instance forces that new instance to re-evaluate your current quests and objectives, and as a result, your previously bugged quest will be workable.

Loading into a new instance can take several re-log attempts. You don't need to restart the whole game. Simply logging out to your character selection screen and logging back in is sufficient. I've had to re-log 4 or 5 times for a quest before it worked, but it does work.

Also, there is a command (/camp) that seems to force you into a new instance, so that may be of help as well.

Comment: Another way of forcing yourself into a new instance is to get a group invite from someone in another instance and then teleporting to them. However, I'm not sure how to tell who is in a different instance than you without physically standing near them when you should be able to see them.

Answer (score 1):

Since there are no *"console cheats"* to put it that way as there was in **Skyrim** i.e., it saddens me to say that there's nothing else you can do besides try to log in again and wait, wait and wait until it resets.

In addition to that, you should always [report those glitches](https://help.elderscrollsonline.com/app/ask) so in a *"near future"* it gets fixed by ESO and people stop getting annoyed by them. Just remember to provide as much information as you can, or else you will most likely be ignored and get a custom answer message. *(we've all been there)*

Answer (score 0):

I had the Tovisa ghost bug. I stood next to her and logged out of the game and back in. She still appeared ghosted but she started talking and moving around.  I followed her behind a boulder where she became solid and I could talk to her. Hopefully it works for you.